# angularJS dynamic tables into tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting angularJS. For my company I need to create a ticketing module to recuperate existing tickets from my database, create new tickets and other things like that.

I decided to work with angularJS and Firebase.
For the moment, I have added my tabs with ui bootstrap tabset. It works fine.
But I want to create, inside these tabs,a dynamic table to collect my tickets.

Here is my current code :

demandescpm.js

```
angular.module('srpTicketingApp')
.controller('DemandescpmCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
$scope.awesomeThings = [
    'HTML5 Boilerplate',
    'AngularJS',
    'Karma'
];
$scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Ticket à traiter', content:'Tab for displaying the untreated tickets' },
    { title:'Tickets non lus', content:'Tab for displaying the unread tickets' },
    { title:'Mes tickets et tickets suivis', content:'Tab for displaying the follow\'s tickets' },
    { title:'Nouveau ticket', content:'Tab for creating new tickets' },
    { title:'Paramètres', content:'Tab for creating and displaying new categories & subcategories' },
    { title:'Recherche', content:'Tab for searching tickets' },
    { title:'Statistiques', content:'Tab to see Wallboard CPM' }
];'
```

demandescpm.html

```
<div ng-controller="DemandescpmCtrl">
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
        {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

And what it looks like for the moment :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYsgE.png

Is it possible to add dynamically my tables into my tabs-content to recover tickets or am I beginning the wrong way with my current code ?

Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is bad but it's not my mother tongue :)

Comment: Your screenshot seems to render the data as you've described it. It's hard to tell what isn't working.

Comment: I wanted tables into my Tab but that's good I found a way and it works =)